# How to save and play a video file only through the Application in Android

Tags: android, file, video, save

I want to save a number of **video files** through the application on the mobile so that the user can not open the saved files and the files **can only be run through the program** and if the user finds the storage location of the desired file, **can not that video file To run**. In general, only **saved files can be run through the application**.

Like the image below, the video file is found but can not be played, this file is opened only by the Application:

**Even if we convert this file to video file format, it will still not run**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just store it in your app's file directory.  Those are private to your app and cannot be accessed by other apps or by users.  It won't prevent a user who has rooted his device, but nothing can really prevent that.

Comment: If the user roots his phone, he can access the file. I just want the file to run through the Application

Comment: @MohammadHasanSalmanian There is no way to beat root. A root user can access and file on the device he wants, there is no way to prevent that.  You can encrypt the file, but since you'd need to decrypt it on the same device, a hacker could trivially find it.  Or he could just rerecord it by taking a video recording of his screen.  In the end, you're adding complexity for little to no gain.

Comment: How can I encode the file and decode it again?